# Access denied when executing program from another drive than C:

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

My setup is as following: I have a core library written in C++ (Visual C++ project in Visual Studio) that compiles to a DLL, and I have C# project that utilizes that DLL. The core library uses disk access for persistence, for instance something along the lines of:

```
std::string path = ...;
if (access(path.c_str(), F_OK) == -1) {
    if (mkpath(path.c_str()) == -1) {
        Log::Message(WARN, "Unable to make path: %s (%s)\n", path.c_str(), strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

The path is predefined to be in the AppData directory.

I have found that it works fine if I execute from the C: drive however if I execute from another drive, e.g. a mapped network drive, I get a "Permission denied" error when trying to create the folder.

I assume this is due to some restrictions in the .NET runtime but is there a way that I can configure it - preferably compile-time or by asking the user for permission? I have tried running as administrator but it makes no difference.

EDIT:
Added the the inner code.
Output from log is

```
Unable to make path: C:/Users/mattimmer/AppData/Roaming/MyApp/Assets (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Obfuscating the essential code with `...` does not help us help you.  The traditional mistake is accidentally relying on the default drive and default directory.  Always use the full path, including the drive letter.  The path to the user's AppData must always be retrieved with SHGetKnownFolderPath() or the APPDATA environment variable.  Or let your .NET code help with Environment.GetFolderPath().

Comment: Sorry, for the time being I'm just logging the code and to me it wasn't the essential part as it is the mkpath that fails. I am using full paths. I will update my question.

Comment: Try to make a [MCVE] in C++ only that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks I was making one and it made me realize what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find out what went wrong. I thought that mkpath was part of a library so I didn't even consider looking there, when in reality it wasn't. The implementation of mkpath would loop through the folders in the path and invoke `_mkdir`. When run from another drive, the first step, which essentially is `_mkdir("C:")`, would fail with EACCES (Permission Denied), however all subsequent paths would succeed. So my solution was to change the implementation so that it would keep trying even if it failed with EACCES.